# SymfonyのコマンドコンソールからOracleの統計情報を取得する方法

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2, oracle

下記のURLを参考にコマンドを作成しているのですが、Doctrineを使用したOracleの統計情報の取得方法がわかりませんでした。
http://docs.symfony.gr.jp/symfony2/cookbook/console.html

以下のようなコードで実行するとORA-00900になってしまいます。

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$execute = "execute dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(OWNNAME=>'test'," .
                                                 "TABNAME=>'TEST_TABLE'," .
                                                 "CASCADE=>true," .
                                                 "NO_INVALIDATE=>false)";
$connection->executeQuery($execute);
```

Answer (score 1):

`EXECUTE`はPL/SQLではなくSQL*Plusのコマンドだったと思います。

```
BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(...); END;
```

のようにすればよいのではないでしょうか。